# Как записать целое число с клавиатуры в регистр на Assembler?

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Нужно написать программу, которая будет выполнять вычисление этого выражения:

> y = 10 - b + 4

Нужно, чтобы значение переменной `b` вводилось с клавиатуры во время выполнения программы. Как это реализовать? Остальной код, я думаю, должен выглядеть так:

```
 mov ax, 10
 mov bx, 4
 add ax, bx
 b : ; заносим значение с клавиатуры (оно может быть и отрицательным, но можно использовать флаги )
 mov bx, b
 sub ax,bx
 y: dd 0
 mov [y], ax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

задача сводится к преобразованию строки в число.

```
section .data
    buff resb 10; буфер для строки

section .text
    global _start

_start:
mov rax, 0; номер системного вызова
mov rdi, 1; файловый дескриптор
mov rsi, buff; указатель на буффер
mov rdx, 10; количество символов

syscall

xor rcx, rcx
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdi, rdi
xor rdx, rdx
mov rcx, 10; количество итераций цикла
mov rax, 1; множитель разряда
mov r8, 10
for:
    mov rbx, [buff+rcx]; получаем символ из буфера
    and rbx, 255
    cmp rbx, 0
    je no; если пустой то идём на следующую итерацию 
    cmp rbx, 10; в конец строки может дописываться символ переноса строки
    je no


    sub rbx, '0'; делаем из символа число

    mov rsi, rax; сохраняем множитель
    mul rbx; умножаем число на множитель разряда
    add rdi, rax; прибавляем к итоговому числу
    mov rax, rsi

    mul r8; переводим множитель на следующий разряд 

    no:
    dec rcx
cmp rcx, 0
jge for
```

p.s. момент с записью строки может отличатся в зависимости от os. приведённый пример для linux.

Comment: ещё есть способ через сишную функцию `scanf` но у меня она не заработала так что добавлять в ответ не стал.